Why does SQL Server consider 1 in HAVING and SUM in SELECT as different?
I'm facing an issue with SQL Server where the HAVING clause does not recognize the SUM of a FLOAT column as equal to 1, even though the SUM in the SELECT appears to be 1. Here's a simplified example of my query:

SELECT R.Data, R.Categoria, R.PlanoID, sum(Valor)
        FROM Base.dbo.TabelaExemplo R
        WHERE R.Data = '20241101'
             AND R.CategoriaGrupo < 0
        GROUP BY R.Data, R.Categoria, R.PlanoID
        HAVING SUM(R.Valor) <> 1

result:
enter image description here
the query works fine when I use ROUND(SUM(RP.Valor), 0) in HAVING clauses, like this:
HAVING ROUND(SUM(RP.Valor), 0) <> 1

I cannot change the underlying table schema yet, which uses the FLOAT data type for the Valor column.
This behavior is inconsistent. In tests with other databases using the same schema and similar data (with values containing different decimal places), the original query works as expected without needing ROUND.
I only need to understand why this happens

Is floating-point math broken?

This question is similar to: SQL Server Having clause not filtering as expected with float. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Rounding values to a common precision is one possible solution, but be careful that you do not overround. Do you really want a sum of 0.5678 to pass the test or perhaps just much closer values like 0.9999999999999123? If forced to calculate in floating point, figure out what the potential accumulated rounding errors might be and also what your tolerance in in your logic. Pick a rounding factor that falls in between.
